# Camera stops by itself while shooting, or shows no battery, then ok again?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, battery, canon-7d

Here is what happen to me lately.

I was shooting inside a home, doing some HDR photos with my Canon 7D (settings were : timer 2 sec + high speed shooting + ExpoComboAEB) so basically the camera takes 3 shots with 1 click of the shutter button. It was working, as always did, then the camera stopped after the first or second frame (didn't reach 3rd one).

Thought it was the battery, so I changed it. Same problem. I have 4 Canon batteries. They were all very well charged the day before the shooting. None of them solve the problem. So I stopped that shooting, made some tests, and called Canon.

Today, I still have not sent my camera body to repair, as it still works fine. But I found out that shooting as describe above, or shooting on the full auto mode, makes my camera switch off, just like that. Sometime before even one photo is completely taken, sometimes between 2-3 shots. Sometime the LCD display on top of the body indicates the battery is empty (but it is not), and sometimes the LCD says nothing, just like if not even one battery was inserted inside. There is no Error message showing. How weird !!

Anybody else experience anything like that ???
Related to camera firmware (1.1.1) ?
Related to the body itself ?
Related to all my 4 batteries (I dont think so)
Related to the original Canon charger ?

Comment: have you checked and cleaned the battery contacts?  If the LCD is showing battery is drained, and it is not, maybe the contacts are dirty or otherwise not making good contact?

Comment: Maybe it's a loose screw shorting things out? See: http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?p=17222208#post17222208

Answer (score 1):

If your camera is exhibiting behavior other than what you should expect it to do under certain conditions and selected settings then your 7D needs to take a trip to the nearest Canon service center.